# Not updating multipale row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$match_id = 123; // this is the value to be updated
$update_item_number = "(3,4,5)"; // this is the id no where the value to be updated
//update query
$orders = "UPDATE orders SET item_number='$match_id' WHERE order_id IN'".$update_item_number ."'";
mysql_query($orders);
```

this query not updating, I am stuck here please help me...

Comment: Does `mysql_error` says anything ?

Comment: Add some call to `mysql_error()` to see, if the database returned error messages.

Comment: echo the query and run in query browser or other mysql editor directly

Comment: Remove quotes from the `IN` clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your query:

```
"UPDATE orders SET item_number=$match_id WHERE order_id IN $update_item_number";
```

You do not need apostrophes for integers (they are optional, but better use pure int value).

Also in `IN` statement there should not be `'` before and after statement `(...)`.

Comment: @user1600932 If you find my answer helpful, remember to tick the mark on the left from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, we need to remove single quotes around IN tag from the QUERY.

UPDATE

```
$orders = "UPDATE orders SET item_number='$match_id' WHERE order_id IN'".$update_item_number ."'";
mysql_query($orders);
```

TO

```
$orders = "UPDATE orders SET item_number='$match_id' WHERE order_id IN".$update_item_number;
mysql_query($orders);
```

And the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$update_item_number = "(3,4,5)";
```

You cant do like this, as it will take values as a  complete string,

Instead you can do like this-

```
$match_id = 123; // this is the value to be updated
$orders = "UPDATE orders SET item_number='$match_id' WHERE order_id IN (3,4,5)";
mysql_query($orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can helps you:

```
UPDATE 'table_name' SET field_name = $your_value WHERE field_name IN $condition_array;
```